# Wrapper cannot find servlet class Eclipse stopped generating class files for Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I did the following:

1. Run As > Run on Server.
2. It was working fine until a javascript error came out, not sure why and hung the screen. So I killed Eclipse using the task manager.
3. Repeating task 1 no longer generates the class files I need to run the servlet with the following exception:

> Wrapper cannot find servlet class etc.

So, did something go off to stop it from compiling or something? Anyone have any ideas?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class     com.something.media.MediaServlet or a class it depends on
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.something.media.MediaServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please put the real exception message.

Comment: I just tried deleting another projects class file as well. It does not generate the class files anymore.

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer? because you said you killed Eclipse using task manager. If it doesn't work try to clean and build project using Eclipse before running.

Comment: Yeah did all the restarting, cleaning, auto-building all not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either Tomcat's work directory or Eclipse's build directory is dirty. To solve both, do in Eclipse:

- Remove the project from Tomcat deployments by rightclick, *Add/remove projects* on Tomcat.
- Close the project by rightclick project and *Close*.
- Rightclick the Tomcat instance and choose *Clean*.
- Open the project by rightclick project and *Open*.
- Clean the project by *Project > Clean*.
- Add the project to Tomcat again and continue deploying.

Comment: I did something along those lines, I backed up the code, removed the project from Eclipse, recreated the Dynamic Web project and added back the source. After that was some configuring of the web.xml and library files and voila!